# How can a matrix relation be both antisymmetric and symmetric? Explain this image to me.

Tags: relations

Take a look at this picture:
[image]

From what I am reading, antisymmetric means:

$$∀ x ∀ y \,[ R ( x , y ) ∧ R ( y , x ) ⇒ x = y ]$$

However, $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$, $X\ne Y$. I understand how this is symmetric but how is this antisymmetric? I got this from my professor and my book explains that they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Closely related is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270557/28900).

Comment: Much belated: it is *not* antisymmetric, for precisely the reason you state. We have $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ related, but $1\neq 2.$

Answer (score 2):

Consider matrix which has ones on diagonal and zeros on other places.
Symmetric property:
$\forall a,b\in X$ $aRb\implies bRa$.
Antisymmetric property:
$\forall a,b\in X$ ($aRb \land bRa)\implies a=b$.
So consider relation $R=\{(x_1,x_1),(x_2,x_2)...(x_n,x_n)\}$ s.t. $x_i\in X$
As you see both properties are hold, so we get matrix - $a_{ij}=1$ for $i=j$ and $a_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$.